# webrtc rtp header extension playout-delay is not work in chrome

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-chrome, webrtc

Here is my environment:

- render server:UnityRenderStreaming 3.0.0-pre.4. this unity plugin use webrtc m107 to streaming
  video and audio
- client:Chrome 111.0.5563.148 version

I am trying to reduce the jitterbufferdelay in chrome. so I set playout-delay {0, 0} in renderer server. this means max delay = min delay = 0. What I expected is the jitterbufferdelay is near 0 ms. But in fact, I check webrtc stats the jitterbufferdelay is not changed as I have not set playout-delay.

I tried several things to checkeck weather playout-delay rtp header extension being enabled.

- check answer/offer in chrome. the sdp contains `a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay`
- use wireshark to capture rtp packet. [image: playout-delay]. this image shows the rtp packet does have playout-delay data

So why jitterbufferdelay is not reduced. Are there any other parameters that affect this behaviour